# Bind two selectboxes value to a single knockout date property

Tags: javascript, html, binding, knockout.js

I have a knockout object which contains a single property called **created**. This property of time Date contains the date of an event. Then in my html form I have two selectbox inputs: the first is for the hours and the second is for the minutes. These allow the user to select the time, then the selected values should be set on the created property. The following is an example of the code of my form:

```
<form action="..." method="...">
    <select name="hours">
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        ...
        <option value="22">22</option>
    </select>
    <select name="minutes">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        ...
        <option value="30">30</option>
    </select>

    ...
</form>
```

It's a really simple form, however I don't understand how I could bind that inputs to the created value and update only the portion of date that belongs to each input. Basically, when I select an option of the first input I should update the date's hours and when I select an option of the second input the date's minutes should be updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this by adding a [computed observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) into the mix and store the selected minutes and hour in their constituent parts.

Here is a slightly contrived example, but shows the general principle. The computed here is simply concatenating the hour an minute parts together, but presumably *you* would instantiate a Date object instead to do what you need to do:

```
function TimeModel(options) {
    var self = this;

    self.hourOptions = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
    self.minuteOptions = [0, 15, 30, 45];

    self.selectedHour = ko.observable(options.hour || 0);
    self.selectedMinute = ko.observable(options.minute || 0);

    self.selectedDate = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.selectedHour() + ":" + self.selectedMinute();
    });
}
```

I would then bind the `hourOptions` and `minuteOptions` to the respective select boxes and all should be good :)

Check this fiddle for a working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/WickyNilliams/ejjHp/

Comment: I like your solution but as written in the question I have alredy a property which stores the date and I must set the hours/minutes on it. I though I could somehow had an observable binded to the setter methods of the Date object. So I should set the value of the selectboxes to the value of the time and then reflect any change to that property

Comment: If you could write up a jsfiddle you're more likely to get accurate answers as people do not have to distill requirements from plain text, it's there for them to see. EDIT: also, i think you should just expand the approach i outlined above, store each part of the date individually and use a computed to calculate a brand new date every time one part of it changes (there's no real difference to calling `setMinutes` etc instead of new'ing up a `Date` each time)

Comment: This is almost identical to the code in one of my apps (including the 0, 15, 30, 45).  When selectedDate fires, update the actual Date field you want to send back to the server.

Comment: But i wasn't sure *how* the date is input, aside from the time portion which you outlined. Always create a fiddle, it makes everything so much easier. So, making some assumption on how the date might be input, how about this: http://jsfiddle.net/WickyNilliams/ejjHp/2/ as I said it's a simple continuation of the pattern in my original answer